# What's the meaning of "1946" and other numbers on this building?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad, the-suicide-squad-2021

At about 1:48 in The Suicide Squad (2021) there's this scene where Starro crashes through a building with a very prominent "1946" on the facade. Also, the framing of the door & windows below the balcony seems to have a disguised "67" or maybe "678".

[image: 1946]

1946:

[image]

678?:

[image]

Does this have any significance?

There was a mention earlier in the film that Nazi's fled to Corto Maltese (where this scene takes place) after WWII which would have been around 1946. But I don't see any reason for putting that year on this building, specifically.

The year 1946 on the DC [fandom website](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/1946) also doesn't seem to have any relevance.

I did google for the 1946 and also skimmed some lists of easter eggs in the movie but didn't find anything explaining this.

Comment: Putting the year buildings are built on their frontage is quite a common practice, so the 1946 could simply be when the building was built (linking into when the Nazis arrived)

Comment: I feel like the '1946' is either the year of the building or address, but the '678' is interesting. It almost looks like there is a 3 in front of it as well.

Comment: @A.Steer true, but this was probably a CGI scene which makes it very intentional for the movie. And normally those dates are not so obvious as in this example.

Comment: The `678` in the window seem to be made from the window mullions that simply haven't broken away. Much like a [multi segment LED display](https://www.instructables.com/Multiplexing-7-Segment-displays-with-Arduino-and-S/) makes digits by only lighting certain segments. Sure, because it's CGI, it's intentional that it's this way, but the `8` on the right could be `68` or `b8` because of the way the frames are broken out.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree, the numbers shown in the window are not 100% clear what their values are.